# Wide accents in Times font are not positioned correctly

Tags: accents, italic, mtpro, newtx, times

I use `txfonts` or `newtx` packages to typeset in Times font (NimbusRomNo9L). However, wide accents in math mode are too wide or placed incorrectly, such that they touch the next symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{txfonts}   
\begin{document}
\[ \widehat{T}^2 \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Solution:**

As answered by "Mico", `mtpro2` package has better symbols/typesetting for wide accents. However, its *Lite* version is incomplete. So I used `newtx` for text and math; and instead of `\widehat`,`\widetilde`,... I used the `\what`,`\wtilde`,... symbols form "MathTime" package, as defined below:

```
%%%% Times font (NimbusRomNo9L) for text and math using Newtx package
\usepackage{newtxtext} %
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm} % AMS packages
\usepackage{textcomp} % required for special glyphs
\usepackage[varg,varbb,cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ntxrj} %old-style figures in text

%%%% Define wide accents using symbols from Math Time Pro font
\DeclareFontEncoding{LMP2}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LMP2}{mtt}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontFamily{LMP2}{mtt}{\skewchar\font48}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP2}{mtt}{m}{n}{<-7> mt2syf <7-9> mt2sys <9-> mt2syt}{\skewchar\font32} 
\DeclareSymbolFont{mtsymbols}{LMP2}{mtt}{m}{n} 
\DeclareMathAccent{\what}  {\mathord}{mtsymbols}{"79}
\DeclareMathAccent{\wtilde}{\mathord}{mtsymbols}{"7A}
\DeclareMathAccent{\wcheck}{\mathord}{mtsymbols}{"7B}
\DeclareMathAccent{\wbar}  {\mathord}{mtsymbols}{"78}
```

Comment: When I run your MWE, everything works fine for me.  What's your compilation route?

Comment: The accent `widehat` touches the superscript 2. Isn't it necessary to have some clearance there?

Comment: I tried the `newtxmath` and `mathptmx` packages which also offer Times variants and the latter didn't have this issue.

Comment: @marczellm, `newtx` has the same problem, and `mathptmx` is very old with much more issues.

Comment: @Aydin `\widehat` should be used only when really necessary; the horizontal positioning of the symbols disregards its width. So either you say `\hat{T}^{2}` or `\widehat{T}^{\,2}`. I'd prefer the former.

Comment: @egreg, `\hat` is too small on wide symbols like capital W. I need a wider hat accent with fixed width on all letters, but not that wide. I tried to define a new accent, but it drastically slowed down the compilation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to give the [mtpro2](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) (MathTime Professional II) package a try, as it provides a good-looking "widehat" accents. It does a similarly good job for "widetilde" accents.

Caveat: The full `mtpro2` package isn't free; however, the package's "lite" subset, which is all that's needed for this example, *is* free of charge.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{times}        % text font
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % math font
\begin{document}
$ \hat{T}^2 \quad \widehat{T}^2 $
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Addendum**: For the sake of comparison, here's what results from running the preceding MWE with the `mathptmx` package instead of the `mtpro2` package: The superscipt "2" sits a tiny little bit lower -- which may be desirable -- but the "widehat" accent is (to my taste) too dominant.

[image]

Comment: There are many symbols in "newtx" those are not available in the light version of "mtpro2". Can I use "newtx" and keep the `\widehat` from mtpro2, or use "mtpro2" and keep the additional symbols of "newtx"? _____ P.S. Generally "newtx" typesets slightly better than "mtpro2 light" to my taste, although the difference is not that much.

Comment: @Aydin - I guess any answers will depend importantly on *which* symbols and accents you're going to mix-and-match. Please consider posting a new question, to ask specifically how you might certain accents and characters from different math fonts.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to use "mtpro2 light" with "newtxtext", and bold symbols from "bm" package. However, the kerning of bold symbols is terrible! And there is no matching "mathcal", "mathbb" and "mathscr" fonts.

Comment: @Aydin - Indeed, I believe that if you want to use the mtpro2 package with matching mathcal, mathbb, mathscr, and mathfrak alphabets, you'll have to invest in the *full*, rather than in the "lite", version of the package. The good news is that, relative to some of the other commercial font packages that provide full support for LaTeX, the `mtpro2` package is reasonably affordable. Of course, "reasonable" is a very subjective criterion.

Comment: I agree that `mtpro2` is an affordable _full_ package. If I stay with `times` fonts, I would bye `mtpro` and give it a try. However, after using the _light_ version for few hours, I realized that some basic mathematical symbols are not well balanced for times typeface. And the overal appearance and typesetting of `newtx` is superior (to my taste). The question is, how can I solve the `\widehat` issue of 'newtx' while keeping the rest of the package untouched?

Comment: @Aydin - Please consider posting a new question on the subject of mixing characters and accents from different math fonts.